# Python through java runtime charset problems

Tags: java, python, character-encoding

I am sending some greek text ("αλεξ") to my python program and I expect to get a popup window showing "αλεξ" but instead I get "Î±Î»ÎµÎ¾". Then I print the text parsed in and get it back to my java program, the result is "αλεξ" again! I am assuming the problem is the charset on my python program but I read somewhere that python3 uses by default utf-8.
Here is my Java Program :

```
    public void run() {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String commands = "python -u C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\PythonProjects\\inputOutput.py";
        Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
        // read from terminal of the program
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        // write on the terminal of the program
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(s=new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        System.out.println(s.getEncoding());
        boolean telegramStarted = false;
        String s;
        while ((s=in.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(s);
            if (telegramStarted |s.equals("started")) {
                out.write("αλεξ");
                out.newLine();
                out.flush();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the Python Script :

```
import ctypes

print('started')
while True :
   name = input('Enter your name: ')
   ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, name, "Greetings", 1)
   print('Hello', name, '!')
```

Comment: You're accessing C code directly through ctypes, so `windll.user32.MessageBox` is probably using your user's locale's default charset for encoding and decoding (maybe cp1253, if the locale is Greek?).